# How to run specific part of a function in a code when code has been run for x times in python?

Tags: python, iterator, iteration

I have a code that has several functions and the number of iteration of code is 10.

```
def vectfit_auto(f, s, n_poles=5, n_iter=10,loss_ratio=1e-2, rcond=-1,):

for _ in range(n_iter):
    poles, Zeros, H = vectfit_step(f, s, poles)


    poles_list.append(poles)
```

I want to add some lines to the **`vectfit_step`** (one of my functions) as below for modification:

```
from iteration number of 5 to 10
do something
```

I want that the code runs like before, and my modification be applied only from the iteration number of 5 to the end.
How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: `for i in range(10): if i > 5: do something`?

Answer (score 1):

```
#i takes values between begin and (end - 1)
for i in range(begin, end):
   do_something()

#In your case start = 5 and end = 11
for i in range(5, 10+1):
   do_something(i)

#You might use _, if you are not interested in the value of i
for _ in range(5, 11):
   do_something()
```

Comment: As we will not use `i` in any thing I would suggest using `_`